# Why doesn't code insight in PHPEd work with the Zend Framework?

Tags: ide, code-completion, phped

I am currently working with the [Zend Framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zend_Framework) and I use [PHPEd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHPEd) as my favourite PHP editor. I have already seen that the IDE can trace my own functions and libraries and display them in the code insight. How can I add the libraries of Zend Framework to the code insight?

They are loaded with a internal autoload function of the Zend Framework, so PHPEd can't find the points where they are included and doesn't show them in the list of functions.
Is there a possibility to tell PHPEd always to show the Zend Framework functions and classes in the code insight?

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question but I can tell you that Aptana which I use for ZF application development generates these links and auto-completion works fine, even if you use the Loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after reinstalling NuSphere a third time it finally works. I have no clue why...

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me in [PhpED](http://www.nusphere.com/products/phped.htm) when I tried ZF code, from the beginning. 
To have any 3rd party code appeared in Code Insight, you need to either include corresponding directory into the project list of additional directories or just place the directory with code as a project subdirectory. Then open [Code Explorer](http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_code_explorer_tab.htm) and check for the framework classes. If they don't appear (for any reason) for longer than 5-6sec, just press refresh in the popup.

Comment: Just look at the date of the post... it was 2009. And it seems to have been just some bug in my installation.

Answer (score 0):

They (NuSphere) just released PhpED V11.0 which has full support for ZF etc. - http://www.nusphere.com/products/php_frameworks.htm